# problem when copying a file over putty ssh to my windows machine

Tags: ssh, sh, putty

i want to copy file from remote server that i connect with the following paramters

```
Ip : 192.168.1.1 
port : 2202
```

then i log in with user and password :

```
 user:root
 pass:1234
```

but when i try to use this script it shows that  connection is refused

```
pscp 192.168.1.1:/etc/hosts c:\temp\example-hosts.txt
```

is that correct or i should put the user and password somewhere to authenticate and be able to copy the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the port as it's not the standard port.

Try

```
pscp -P 2202 192.168.1.1:/etc/hosts c:\temp\example-hosts.txt
```

Comment: thanks man it worked